# Infinite UIStepper in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistepper

Is it possible to set an infinite maximum value on a `UIStepper`? If not, is there an alternative to not having limits in counting?

Comment: You need to update your question and clearly explain what you are actually trying to do and what issue you have actually run into.

Comment: What would be the use of an infinite maximum value? By definition, no one could ever step that far.

Answer (score 5):

A `UIStepper` uses a `Double` for its `maximumValue` property. Set it to `Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude`.

`Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude` isn't infinite, but it's really freaking huge. (≈1.80e+308).

### EDIT

Actually, it looks like you can say

```
stepper.maximumValue = Double.infinity
```

That appears to work.

Note that if your step value isn't very large, when your value gets large enough that it requires scientific notation to display, you're going to have a tough time showing changes in value. Plus, at very large magnitudes, floating point numbers lose precision. Increasing a very large double by a value of 1 might not change its value.

### EDIT #2:

I just tried it, and if you set

```
stepper.maximumValue = Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude
```

and

```
stepper.value = Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude / 2
```

Then in theory, when you tap the `+` on the stepper (with a default `stepValue` of 1) then the value should change. However, at a value of `Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude/2`, a change in value of 1 is too small to change the mantissa of the value at all. At the default stepValue of 1, when the stepper.value is `Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude / 2`, tapping the stepper does not cause any change in the stepper's value.

Comment: After doing this, I tried to go back to a maximumValue of 100, but then when I try to tap the stepper, the app freezes and also the close-and-reopen operation doesn't make it work again. What happened?

This only happens on real devices. The simulator works normally

Comment: I have no idea. Edit your question to show your code that crashes. Better yet, post a link to a minimum project that exhibits this behavior.